# What does 'as' mean when importing a module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does it mean when you import something as multiple? so for example,

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

This is just an example from react router and the javascript documentation only shows example of one declaration after 'as'

It looks like it's importing BrowserRouter as Router, Route and Link so all three variables referred to the same library. If I am right, why would you ever want to do that?

So is it the same as `var Router, Route, Link = require('react-router-dom').BrowserRouter();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not at all like that! It's a harmony feature that was added to the Import/Export functionality.

It's the same as this:

```
let tmp = require("react-router-dom")
let Router = tmp.BrowserRouter
let Route = tmp.Route
let Link = tmp.Link
```

Or simply:

```
const {BrowserRouter: Router, Route, Link} = require("react-router-dom")
```

Comment: No worries! ES6 syntax also added

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

selectively imports `BrowserRouter`, `Route` and `Link` from `react-router-dom`. The `as Router` statement makes `BrowserRouter` available under the name `Router` (instead of `BrowserRouter`). The names of `Route` and `Link` are not changed.

It is equivalent to:

```
const Router = require("react-router-dom").BrowserRouter;
const Route = require("react-router-dom").Route;
const Link = require("react-router-dom").Link;
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `as` in an import statement allows you rename the module you're importing. It would be equivalent to the following:

```
let Router = require("react-router-dom").BrowserRouter
let Route = require("react-router-dom").Route
let Link = require("react-router-dom").Link
```

Answer (score 0):

Import is ES6 new syntax, in your example, it's loading three class from module 'react-router-dom', the name for BrowserRouter is too long, so you can use an alias for it, which called Router.

import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";

The commonJS equivalent syntax will be:

```
var Router = require('react-router-dom').BrowserRouter,
    Route = require('react-router-dom').Route,
    Link = require('react-router-dom').Link;
```

I attached a link below: you will find more details.

[import syntax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)